# how can I reshape numpy array? I am getting cannot reshape array of size 87880 into shape (130,20,26,1) error

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

My code is as follows:

```
    idxs = [np.where(np.argmax(y_test, axis=1) == i)[0][0]
        for i in range(nb_classes)]
if targeted:
    if viz_enabled:
  # Initialize our array for grid visualization
        

        adv_inputs = np.array(
                    [[instance] * nb_classes for instance in x_test[idxs]],
                    dtype=np.float32)
    else:
        adv_inputs = np.array(
                        [[instance] * nb_classes for
                        instance in x_test[:source_samples]], dtype=np.float32)

    one_hot = np.zeros((nb_classes, nb_classes))
    one_hot[np.arange(nb_classes), np.arange(nb_classes)] = 1

    adv_inputs = adv_inputs.reshape(
        (source_samples * nb_classes, img_rows, img_cols, nchannels))
    adv_ys = np.array([one_hot] * source_samples,
                  dtype=np.float32).reshape((source_samples *
                                             nb_classes, nb_classes
```

I want to reshape adv_inputs. x_test shape is (5982, 20, 26, 1) and y_test shape as (5982, 13)

Comment: which line is giving you the error? 87880 elements indeed cannot be reshapen to (130,20,26,1) since 87880/(130*20) = 33.8 which is not an int. How'd you get 87880 elements from (5982,20,26,1)?

Comment: I am trying to implement cleverhans adversarial CW attack. So its giving me error on the following line:adv_inputs = adv_inputs.reshape(
        (source_samples * nb_classes, img_rows, img_cols, nchannels)) So as per my understanding its generating the adversarial input.